# Javascript RSS Feed Validation

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

hello i want to create some thing like this,

http://mobile.conduit.com/create-app-m.aspx

I need to validate rss feeds before submit form,

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">    
<input type="text" name="url" type="text" id="url" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="button2" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

if any one enter text in the url text box i need to check is it a valid rss feed (need to check even the one letter changes as http://mobile.conduit.com/create-app-m.aspx ** not in onchange event of textbox ) and i need to show loading gif when the validation is in process. if it's success need to show another gif.

and if it is valid  rss, user can submit the form, otherwise he can't and should show a error message.

hope a help for this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this with client side JavaScript. The same origin policy would prevent your code from accessing arbitrary URIs.

You could either use a proxy on your system to request the data (and then build an RSS validator in JS) or get your server to do the validation and return a success or failure response. The latter would probably be easier due to the abundance of RSS libraries for most languages that are popular on the server.

Comment: i dont need need to polpulate, i just need to check if it's a valid feed.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to tell if it is valid if you can't see what it is made of?